# How to watermark all files in folder with ffmpeg? in windows

Tags: windows, video, ffmpeg

when I use `for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark-image.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4" pause` i makes all the videos to 0kb.

Comment: What output do you receive when trying to run the script? Does the same ffmpeg command (without the 'for' loop) successfully watermark _one_ file?

Comment: it doesn't even open